# Can I share my Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links account across two devices?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-duel-links

I have been playing *[Yu-Gi-Oh! Duel Links](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yu-Gi-Oh!_Duel_Links)* on my iPad and am enjoying playing it on a larger screen. I would like to play it on my phone as well when I am on the go. But when I install it on my phone, the game doesn't automatically pick up where I left off (I figured it might take into account that it might see that I am logged in to the same Game Center account on both).

Is there any way that I can share an account across two devices?

To be clear, I don't want to be *playing* the game on two devices simultaneously. I'm just wanting to log in to one device at a time, but have it update with any progress I made on the other device.

Comment: Is the question specifically about iOS environment, or is it including cross-OS (e.g. iOS <-> Android)? Most of the mobile games I know don't allow cross-OS link, but I don't know about this particular game.

Comment: @antimo I am doing it on an iPad to an iPhone, but it would be good to know if there is a way between iOS and Android as well.

Comment: This was asked a year ago. Why is it at the front

Comment: @hakalo I see a notice that reads "bumped to the homepage by Community♦ 42 mins ago. This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed." It does that from time to time when all answers have received zero upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: ah. I see now..

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the game and click on Settings, there's an option for Data Transfer Settings. You'll make a Konami account and link your Duel Links data to it. Then on the device you also want to play it on, when you launch the game, instead of clicking on "Initiate link", click on "Data transfer" and sign into the Konami account.